# Knockout js - visible binding with negation does not work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to use the visible data binding with a negation and it does not seem to work. 
I found several questions in stackoverflow which specify that the NOT binding should be used as an expression. But in my case i am just using the length property, so i am not sure how to use an expression. Here is my example

```
<div class="form-group" data-bind="visible:!users.length == 0">
<span>Some message here...</span
</div>

<div class="form-group" data-bind="visible:users.length > 0">
<span>User data grid here...</span
</div>
```

Comment: Is your `users` property an observable array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing `users` is an observableArray and therefore you should be doing this:

```
data-bind="visible:users().length !== 0"
```

An even better and more clear intent would be to create a computed property on your view model and bind to that instead:

```
showUsers = ko.computed(function(){

   return _this.users().length > 0;

});
```

Then your bindings become:

```
data-bind="visible:showUsers"
```

Or

```
data-bind="visible:!showUsers()"
```

Here is a [jsFiddle showing a full example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/E58u2/) using various techniques.

Comment: +1 For showing the computed alternative, you see way too much inline JavaScript in KO bindings these days

Comment: THanks Josh. I was trying to use the expression directly in the data-bind. Looks like it is not possible. I will use this approach.